# Layout Preview showing blank screen with Coordinator layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, gradle

I got xml codes (with drawables...) and implement it in my project, but it's not working

[image]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.md.splashloginsignup"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation "com.mikepenz:iconics-core:3.0.2@aar"
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:5.0.6.0@aar'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0-alpha1'


    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
}
```

and here's the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/profileBackground">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/profilePrimaryDark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:background="@drawable/profile_bk">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/profile_round" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="\@appsnippuser"
                    android:textSize="28dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="developer@appsnipp.com"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@color/profileBackground">

                    <View
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/profile_bk"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                 />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_profile" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

i tried changing many versions in the gradle but still not working

maybe also the problem from styles.xml, i can't post it because of an error

"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: I think it doesn't matter to your XML. Please see if coordinatorlayout without items in it works or not.